# splitting a column using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file like shown below. The 9th column has values joined by **.

```
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +       SNR81   chrXV   234357  0.0003015891774815342**0.131826816475   +
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +       SNR81   chrXV   234385  0.0002208827994288481**0.0118547789578  +
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +       SNR81   chrXV   234396  0.0001799579220002955**0.00583993781634 +
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +       SNR81   chrXV   234410  0.003451057940295026**0.00352844797952  +
```

I want to have an output where I can have the 2 values as sep columns. How can I do this in awk.

This is the output I want. Showing the first line of the output:

```
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +   SNR81   chrXV   234357  0.0003015891774815342   0.131826816475  +
```

Comment: Please always specify your column separator. Since this is a gff file, I assume it's tab separated but people won't know this unless you state it.

Answer (score 8):

No idea why people are using cat to pipe the file into awk, and the tr answer only translates one character into another, so any `*` is converted to a `space`.

Simple awk solution

```
awk -F"**" '$1=$1' OFS="\t" file
```

For tab between all fields

```
awk 'sub(/\*\*/," "){$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" file
```

And one more

```
awk 'gsub(/(*| )+/,"\t")' file
```

Sed command

```
sed 's/[* ]\+/\t/g' file
```

tr command

```
tr -s '* ' '\t'  < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be awk? Why not `cat file | tr '**' '  '` Just replacing the **'s with three spaces

Comment: tr '**' '\t' works too. Wanted it as tab separated. Does 3 spaces equivalent to a tab?. I want to see how awk would do this?

Comment: How about `cat file | awk -F "**" '{print $1 "\t" $2}'`

Comment: Ahh I didn't thought of field separator FS. You just separated the fields on **. The file was already tab separated so everything came out ok. Also let's say columns were separated by single space and I want the output as tab separated. What should be done. Can we specify 2 FS? nICE SOLUTION tHANKS!!!

Comment: With a single space I'd use a gsub as follows `cat file| awk '{gsub("[**| ]","\t"); print $0 }'`

Comment: I don't think `tr` does what you think it does. It transliterates one character at a time so I am not sure how you could get it to replace two `*`s with three spaces

Comment: @kevino_17 why are you using cat when awk takes files as arguments ?

Comment: @kevino_17 That gsub won't work, it will replace all spaces with tabs meaning some fields will have multiple tabs between them.

Comment: @1_CR `tr` could be used, just not in the way shown in this answer

Comment: I had the same idea with `sed` but `tr` actually works better with tabs, good thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

```
cat text.txt  |awk '{ split($9,a , "**"); printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8, a[1], a[2],$10); }'
```

Output is:

```
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +   SNR81   chrXV   234357  0.0003015891774815342   0.131826816475  +
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +   SNR81   chrXV   234385  0.0002208827994288481   0.0118547789578 +
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +   SNR81   chrXV   234396  0.0001799579220002955   0.00583993781634    +
chrXV   234346  234546  snR81   +   SNR81   chrXV   234410  0.003451057940295026    0.00352844797952    +
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacement of one substring by another is clearly work for sed. If you want it in awk, I assume you wish to do some additional processing by awk. To do so, you should just use the regex field separator:

```
awk -F'(**| )' '{.you code here.; print $10}'
```

Comment: That regex is awful and wont work. -1 for the fact that you also have answered as though you understand what you are doing.

Comment: Could you please explain why regex is "awful" and also what is the reason it "wont work". I have no idea. I tested it before posting and it does work perfectly.

Comment: What do you think it does ?

Comment: It uses either ' **' or ' ' as column separator - something that nobody else suggested in other answers. And leaves the exact way of output for author.

Comment: I know what you were trying to do, how does using `''` as column separator do what OP wants in any way, also it won't separate based on two `*` as the there is a space before and after it in the regex. Honestly i don't even know why i am explaining this to you as i don't understand how after looking at your code you still don't see how it is completely wrong in every way. Try `-F'(*| )+'` as this would do what you think your current code does.

Comment: Oh, yes, somehow I kept thinking that in author example fields are separated by ' ** ' not by '**'. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'**' 'BEGIN{OFS="   ";} {print $1,$2}' file
```

use '**' as separator and set three whitespaces as output separator