# Split content of specific columns when specific characters are present in those columns

Tags: text-processing, columns, split

I have this data tab delimited:

```
ed00011   89    0.12   NA            NA                      No
ed0002s   28    0.11  c3(3.1e-1)     NA                      No
ed0001    22    0.37   NA            186_CR_NCR8_Ot(1.5e-6)  No
ed0002a   596   0.89  c301(9.5e-2)   17_CY7_Ot(0.03)         Yes
```

I would like to split the 4 and 5th columns based on "(...)" when present. if not present, just have NA.
For example:

```
ed00011   89   0.12  NA    NA       NA             NA          No
ed0002s   28   0.11  c3   3.1e-1    NA             NA          No
ed0001    22   0.37  NA    NA      186_CR_NCR8_Ot  1.5e-6      No
ed0002a   596  0.89 c301  9.5e-2   17_CY7_Ot       0.03        Yes
```

I tried to use the commands suggested here: [splitting a column using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156919/splitting-a-column-using-awk)
But, when I do not have the "(...)", my columns will be messed up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; }
  {
        if (match($4, /\(.*\)/) > 0) {
                $4=substr($4, 1, RSTART - 1)"\t"substr($4, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)
        } else {
                $4=$4"\tNA"
        }

        if (match($5, /\(.*\)/) > 0) {
                $5=substr($5, 1, RSTART - 1)"\t"substr($5, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)
        } else {
                $5=$5"\tNA"
        }
        print
  }' input > output
```

The basic structure here is to check, on every line, if field 4 or field 5 contain a matched pair of parenthesis. If so, then replace that field with a two tab-separated values: the part before the parenthesis and the part inside parenthesis. The RSTART value is where the open parenthesis is, and the RLENGTH value inclueds the closing parenthesis, so that's why you see some length adjustments. If those fields didn't contain parenthesis, then a TAB and "NA" are appended.

Once the columns have been re-computed, the new line is printed.

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = "\t"
}

{
    # Shift some fields to the right to make space for new fields after
    # field 4 and 5.
    $8 = $6
    $6 = $5

    # Try matching "(...)" in $4
    if (match($4, "[(][^)]+[)]")) {
        # Succeeded, make $5 the bit inside the parenthesis
        $5 = substr($4, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
        # ... and $4 the bit before the parenthesis.
        $4 = substr($4, 1, RSTART-1)
    } else
        $5 = "NA"

    # Repeat for $6
    if (match($6, "[(][^)]+[)]")) {
        $7 = substr($6, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
        $6 = substr($6, 1, RSTART-1)
    } else
        $7 = "NA"

    print
}
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
ed00011   89    0.12    NA      NA      NA      NA      No
ed0002s   28    0.11    c3      3.1e-1  NA      NA      No
ed0001    22    0.37    NA      NA      186_CR_NCR8_Ot  1.5e-6  No
ed0002a   596   0.89    c301    9.5e-2  17_CY7_Ot       0.03    Yes
```

The fields are tab-delimited in the output but it looks a bit wonky.  Better when passed through `column -t`, but the actual tabs are lost:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file | column -t
ed00011  89   0.12  NA    NA      NA              NA      No
ed0002s  28   0.11  c3    3.1e-1  NA              NA      No
ed0001   22   0.37  NA    NA      186_CR_NCR8_Ot  1.5e-6  No
ed0002a  596  0.89  c301  9.5e-2  17_CY7_Ot       0.03    Yes
```

Comment: This did not work well for my data, the last column is missing.

Comment: @Paul It is assumed that the input data is six tab-delimited columns. If there are more or if some columns don't have tabs between them, then it would not wok.  You would also loose the last column if you don't do the assignment `$8 = $6`.

Answer (score 1):

**Reliable method**

```
gawk '{
    for(i = 4; i < 6; i++) {
        if($i ~ /\(/) {
            split($i, arr, "[()]")
            $i = arr[1] "\t" arr[2]
        } else {
            $i = $i"\tNA"   
        }
    }
    print
}' OFS='\t' input.txt
```

**Unreliable, but working on your sample, method**

```
sed 's/NA/&\tNA/g; s/(/\t/g; s/)//g' input.txt
```

This command does three simple steps:

1. `s/NA/&\tNA/g` - substitutes all `NA` to double `NA` separated by tab.
2. `s/(/\t/g` - substitutes all opening parentheses to tabs.
3. `s/)//g`- removes all closing parentheses.

It is unreliable, because it does many assumptions: parentheses can happened only in 4 and 5 columns, `NA` string only in 4 and 5 column, the number string in 4 and 5 columns always have the `c3(3.1e-1)` alike format. So, if they will have the `c3` only, without parentheses part, this `sed` command wouldn't work.

But, if your data the same as your sample strictly, this will do the job.

**Output**

```
ed00011 89  0.12    NA  NA  NA  NA  No
ed0002s 28  0.11    c3  3.1e-1  NA  NA  No
ed0001  22  0.37    NA  NA  186_CR_NCR8_Ot  1.5e-6  No
ed0002a 596 0.89    c301    9.5e-2  17_CY7_Ot   0.03    Yes
```

Comment: Exactly, the command sed 's/NA/&\tNA/g; s/(/\t/g; s/)//g' input.txt does not work well for my data, but the "Reliable method" worked very well. Thanks.